# Temperature dependence of order of reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics, reaction-order

In my textbook, it is given that the order of a reaction can change with temperature and pressure, but examples are not given. One possible explanation for this is that the rates of complex reactions are dependent on the rates of the elementary reactions in its mechanism, and at different temperatures, there are different rate determining steps, so the order can change. Is this explanation correct? Are there any examples for the change of order with temperature?

Comment: For gas phase reactions, concentrations are highly sensitive to temperature and pressure, so C vs t data for the same reaction will vary if performed under different P and T conditions. For liquid phase reactions, pressure changes don't matter as much as temperature changes.

Comment: Here is a contrived example. The mechanism of an enzyme-catalyzed reaction changes at high temperatures because those break the enzyme. As a consequence, the uncatalyzed reaction now is faster than the catalyzed reaction.

Comment: Your explanation seems to be correct. The inactivation or altered mechanism of an enzyme or catalyst is an example. I think the reason why examples aren't covered in a typical chemistry curriculum is that complex mechanisms are beyond the scope of introductory general chemistry. By the time students learn about those mechanisms, the fact that the reaction order of the overall reaction changes with temperature is not important compared to specific details about the mechanism itself. Whether two reactions are "the same" when they have different intermediates seems like a matter of semantics.